# React - Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' although MIME type is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I have a React app deployed into an S3 bucket and served via CloudFront. The app works as expected when ran locally. However, when accessed on the cloud, it delivers a blank page.

The following errors are displayed on the console of Firefox:

- `The script from “https://react-app.co.uk/static/js/main.57bf5aad.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`
- `The stylesheet https://react-app.co.uk/static/css/main.762a9cc7.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`
- `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

What I have tried:

1. I made sure the MIME type of `main.57bf5aad.js` is `text/javascript` and the type of  `main.762a9cc7.css` is `text/css` (Accessed through the Metadata of each object).
2. I tried running the app from several browsers with incognito and browser cache invalidation.
3. I've created an invalidation of all files in Cloud Front
4. I've accessed the content of `main.57bf5aad.js` from the S3 bucket, and I don't see any `Content-Type` header under `Response-Headers` on the `Network` tab.
5. Accessed directly Cloud Front domain and I still see the same error. (So no DNS issue)
6. Since I wanted to know if the issue is with CloudFront, I wanted to update the DNS records to point straight to the S3 bucket instead. To do that, I needed to enable Static website hosting, but I get `403: Access Denied` error when I try to access the generated URL (Also tried to make the s3 bucket public and same error still appeared)

My question is, what might be causing the alternation of the Content-Type header and how could I effectively debug the issue?

I can post relevant code if needed, but I'm not sure what part of the code would help determine the issue